# return list from java class to servlet

Tags: java, servlets, gson

I have a table `employee` with three columns `eid,ename,esalary`.`selectclass.java` retrieves data from database `test`and  values are populated in a list named `rows`,then I return the list.

In my servlet`selectclass` I have created the instance of the java class and tried to retrieve the returned list `rows` from the class ( where i made the list) into json but it is not working: it is showing `cannot find symbol of variable rows`.

How could I solve it?
servlet 
    package com.mvc.servlets;

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.mvc.javaclassbeans.employeeselect;
import com.mvc.javaclasses.selectclass;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet(name = "selectservlet", urlPatterns = {"/selectservlet"})
public class selectservlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
     PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();


       try {
           selectclass sclass=  new selectclass();

         Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(sclass.selectfunction(obj));
        out.print(json);

       }catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(selectservlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        out.print("sucess");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(myservlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}
```

Comment: here is the java class http://pastebin.com/58qjsnmr

Comment: `rows` is in method. put it in outside of method.

Comment: Please follow Java coding conventions.  https://www.google.fr/search?q=Please+follow+Java+coding+conventions.&oq=Please+follow+Java+coding+conventions.&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

Use GSON library for that. Here is the sample code

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(list);
```

Try it out

Rewrite your java code to

```
package com.mvc.javaclasses;

    import com.google.gson.Gson;
    import com.mvc.javaclassbeans.employee;
    import com.mvc.javaclassbeans.employeeselect;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    import org.json.*;


    public class selectclass {

        PreparedStatement ps;
        public String query;
        Statement stmt = null;

        public String selectfunction(employeeselect ob) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

                dbconnector dbc = new dbconnector();
                Connection connection = dbc.Open();

                List rows = new ArrayList();
                Map row = null;

                try {
                    ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                    ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
                    int numColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();

                    while (resultSet.next()) {
                        row = new HashMap();
                        for (int i = 1; i < numColumns + 1; i++) {
                            row.put(metaData.getColumnName(i), resultSet.getObject(i));
                        }
                        rows.add(row);
                    }

                    resultSet.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
                String json = new Gson().toJson(rows);
                  return json;


               // return true;
            }


        }
```

And servlet to

```
import com.mvc.javaclassbeans.employeeselect;
import com.mvc.javaclasses.selectclass;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet(name = "selectservlet", urlPatterns = {"/selectservlet"})
public class selectservlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
     PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();


       try {
           selectclass sclass=  new selectclass();


        String json =sclass.selectfunction(obj);
        out.print(json);

       }catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(selectservlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        out.print("sucess");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(myservlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}
```

Comment: i tried it but i want to get the list( which is rows)returned from another javaclass.i couldn't create the object of that class.so when i tried to write String json = new Gson().toJson(list)  an error is showing

Comment: can u explain which type of data you fetch from database.

Comment: above method i change return type to String in your case it is json string. and just display it to the servlet. i didnt  get any error

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
    String json = gson.toJson(sclass.rows);
```

do this

```
    String json = gson.toJson(sclass.selectfunction(obj));
```